# I'm trying to find out if the background is colored or monochrome

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

*I'm trying to find out if the background is colored or monochrome*

I'm making the object in the foreground black I couldn't find a method to find out whether the background is colored or monochrome

> İnput İmage
>   [Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxTwN.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('d2.jpg')
height = np.size(img, 0)
width = np.size(img, 1)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
rect = (0, 7, width, height)
cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, 
cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask == 0) | (mask == 3), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
#plt.imshow(img), plt.axis("off"), plt.show()

newmask = cv2.imread('yenimaske.png', 0)

mask[newmask == 0] = 0
mask[newmask == 255] = 1

mask, bgdModel, fgdModel = cv2.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
mask = np.where((mask == 0) | (mask == 3), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask[:, :, np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img), plt.axis("off"),  plt.show()
```

> [Output İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVnZk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, your code has couple of issues:

1. Your ROI (`rect`) is larger than the  image, and only first 7 rows are used as the background. You might consider defining more precise ROI, or using GC_EVAL mode instead
2. You're extracting foreground instead of background in:

   `mask = np.where((mask == 3) | (mask == 1), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
   img = img*mask[:, :, np.newaxis]`
3. You're interested in color of the image but you're loading the image as black and white in

   `resim = cv2.imread("histogram.jpg", 0)`

Since you're only really interested in saturation (which is amount of "color" in pixels), you should convert your image from BGR color space to HSV space and create histogram of the saturation channel. You actually probably don't need the histogram, and could use a simple thresholding:

```
img = img*mask[:, :, np.newaxis]
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
saturation_threshold = 20 # try different thresholds to see which value works for you
ratio = numpy.count_nonzero(hsv[:,:,1] > saturation_threshold ) / numpy.count_nonzero(mask)
```

`ratio` will be number of pixels which are not grayscale

Comment: `mask = np.where((mask == 0) | (mask == 2), 0, 1).astype('uint8')` [for obvious and probable background](https://www.docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gad43d3e4208d3cf025d8304156b02ba38)

Comment: `img = img*mask[:, :, np.newaxis]` you didn't initialize mask at this point, so it's zero. Also, change mode back to `cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` if you want to use rectangle for initialization